# Redshift Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit on svl_statementtext

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, listagg

Trying to reconstruct my query history from  svl_statementtext using listagg.
Getting error :

> Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit (limit: 65535)

However, I cannot see how or where I have exceeded limit.

My failing query :

```
SELECT pid,xid, min(starttime) AS starttime, 
  pg_catalog.listagg(
        CASE WHEN (len(rtrim(("text")::text)) = 0) THEN ("text")::text ELSE rtrim(("text")::text) END
        , ''::text
    ) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY "sequence") 
    AS query_statement 
FROM svl_statementtext
GROUP BY pid,xid
HAVING  min(starttime) >= '2022-06-27 10:00:00';
```

After the fail, I checked to see if I could find where the excessive size was coming from :

```
SELECT pid,xid, min(starttime) AS starttime, 
  SUM(OCTET_LENGTH(
      CASE WHEN (len(rtrim(("text")::text)) = 0) THEN ("text")::text ELSE rtrim(("text")::text) END
  )) as total_bytes
FROM svl_statementtext
GROUP BY pid,xid
HAVING  min(starttime) >= '2022-06-27 10:00:00'
ORDER BY total_bytes desc;
```

However the largest size that this query reports is 2962
So how/why is listagg complaining about 65535 ??

Have seen some other posts mentioning using listaggdistinct, and catering for when the value being aggregated is null, but none seem to change my problem.

Any guidance appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The longest string that Redshift can hold is 64K bytes.  Listagg() is likely generating a string longer than this. The "text" column in svl_statementtext is 200 characters so if you have more than 319 segments you can overflow this string size.

The other issue I see is that your query will combine multiple statements into one string.  You are only grouping by xid and pid which will give you all statements for a transaction.  Add starttime to your group by list and this will break different statements into different results.

Also remember that xid and pid values repeat every few days so have some date range limit can help prevent a lot of confusion.

You need to add

```
where sequence < 320
```

to your query and also group by starttime.

Here's a query I have used to put together statements in Redshift:

```
select xid, pid, starttime, max(datediff('sec',starttime,endtime)) as runtime, type, listagg(regexp_replace(text,'\\\\n*',' ')) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sequence) || ';' as querytext
from svl_statementtext
where pid = (SELECT pg_backend_pid()) --current session
    and sequence < 320
    and starttime > getdate() - interval '24 hours'
group by starttime, 1, 2, "type" order by starttime, 1 asc, "type" desc ;
```

Comment: Bill, can I ask ... to add the database name for each statement ? STL_QUERY has it for QUERY types, but cannot find same for UTILITY calls ? Appreciate any guidance

Comment: So the database that is currently being connected to is logged as part of the session (connection) information.  pid stands for the process id but is the id of the session.  The session information is kept in 2 places - stv_sessions for currently active connections and stl_sessions for historical / closed sessions.  Remember that pids are recycled over time so also join on timestamp so that you get the correct connection that issued a statement.